# How do you do lowercase prefix filtering with Stratio Cassandra Lucene Index

Tags: cassandra, lucene, stratio, cassandra-lucene-index

Is it possible to do lowercase prefix filtering/querying with Stratio Cassandra Lucene Index?  I haven't been able to find documentation on this particular use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The casing of queries depends on how the labour of the [Lucene text analyzer](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html) used during indexing, and can't be decided in query time. If you want to do case insensitive prefix searches, you should use a mapper with an analyzer producing lowercase terms. These terms will be indexed and matched at search time. For example:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE test
WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1};
USE test;
CREATE TABLE test (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    body TEXT
);

CREATE CUSTOM INDEX test_index ON test ()
USING 'com.stratio.cassandra.lucene.Index'
WITH OPTIONS = {
    'refresh_seconds' : '1',
    'schema' : '{
        fields : {
            body1 : {type :"string", column:"body", case_sensitive:false},
            body2 : {type :"string", column:"body", case_sensitive:true}
        }
    }'
};

INSERT INTO test(id,body) VALUES ( 1, 'foo');
INSERT INTO test(id,body) VALUES ( 2, 'Foo');
INSERT INTO test(id,body) VALUES ( 3, 'bar');
INSERT INTO test(id,body) VALUES ( 4, 'Bar');


SELECT * FROM test WHERE expr(test_index, 
   '{filter:{type:"prefix", field:"body2", value:"f"}}'); -- Returns foo
SELECT * FROM test WHERE expr(test_index, 
   '{filter:{type:"prefix", field:"body2", value:"F"}}'); -- Returns Foo

SELECT * FROM test WHERE expr(test_index, 
   '{filter:{type:"prefix", field:"body1", value:"f"}}'); -- Returns foo and Foo
SELECT * FROM test WHERE expr(test_index, 
   '{filter:{type:"prefix", field:"body1", value:"F"}}'); -- Returns no results
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I am having problems with this and am wondering if the 'case_sensitive:false' only works with type=string and not with type=text...?